# Store String var in awk command

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I have txt file like this:

```
Dupont Charles
Martin Paul
Dupuis Jean
```

I want, for each line, to make a login corresponding to first 2 caracters of each names.
For instance : Dupont Charles ==> duch

```
awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,1)substr($2,1,1))}' liste.txt
```

works perfectly.

but i want to store each login in var and call a bash script (uscript) with that var...

```
awk '{login=tolower(substr($1,1,1)substr($2,1,1));print $login; script1 $login; }' liste.txt
```

But it does not work and the content of login is not what I want.

Comment: Use `var=$(command)` syntax to catch a value.

Comment: How doesn't it work ? What is the content of login and what should it be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to use variables in `awk` is different from Bash. In `awk`, a variable does not have a leading `$`. So what you want to say is:

```
awk '{login=tolower(substr($1,1,1)substr($2,1,1));print login; }' liste.txt
#                                                       ^
#                                                 intead of $login
```

However, you are willing to use a script `script1` with this value. For this, you may want to use `system()` to call an external command............... or use a `while` block to handle all in one.

```
while IFS= read -r name surname
do
    login=${name:0:2}${surname:0:2}
    script1 "$login"  
done < file
```

This uses the same logic to get the 3 first characters of a variable:

```
$ v="123456789"
$ echo ${v:0:3}
123
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, i undertand now!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,2)substr($2,1,2))}' liste.txt | xargs script1
```

e.g. using `echo` instead of `script1` which of course I don't have:

```
$ awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,2)substr($2,1,2))}' liste.txt | xargs echo
duch mapa duje
```

or if `script1` requires 1 arg at a time:

```
awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,2)substr($2,1,2))}' liste.txt | xargs -n1 script1
```

e.g.

```
$ awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,2)substr($2,1,2))}' liste.txt | xargs -n1 echo
duch
mapa
duje
```

Comment: +1 However, I guess the OP will want to call `script1` once per line in the file, which would not be the case with this

Comment: @fedorqui that's what the `-n1` arg for xargs provides but we really don't know if that tool requires 1 arg per invocation or can take a space-separated list.

Comment: Fair enough. Now I see some usefulness to `-n` in `xargs`, I was just using it to join lines (`seq 10 | xargs -n 5`)